# jquery Datepicker - fill input fields on page load

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have the following three input boxes, in an ASP Classic page, each associated with a corresponding jquery datepicker calendar:

```
<br />
Start Date: <input type="text" id="dtpDateStart" name="dtpDateStart" />
<br />
<br />
End Date:   <input type="text" id="dtpDateEnd" name="dtpDateEnd" />
<br />
<br />
Return By:  <input type="text" id="dtpDateReturn" name="dtpDateReturn" />
<br />
```

And the JQuery script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $("#dtpDateStart").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'm/d/yy',
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#dtpDateEnd").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    $("#dtpDateEnd").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'm/d/yy',
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#dtpDateStart").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
            $("#dtpDateReturn").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    $("#dtpDateReturn").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'm/d/yy',
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#dtpDateEnd").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });

});
```

When a date is chosen in the Start Date calendar (dtpDateStart), the End Date (dtpDateEnd) calendar will only allow for a date after the start date to display.  And so on with the return date calendar (dtpDateReturn).

But I now need to add a two more items of functionally:

1. On page load, fill todays date into the Start and End input fields and tomorrows date into the ReturnBy input field.
2. if the StartDate is changed, automatically update the EndDate and ReturnByDate fields to the same date (or +1), if the dates already in them are before the StartDate (otherwise leave them if they are after the StartDate)

I have the first item working elsewhere in a simple calendar with the following:

```
$("#jqDatePicker").datepicker("setDate", new Date);
```

but can't seem to roll it into the above function.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not just set the value of the first datepicker server-side? As for changing the dates of the other fields, you will need to check the datepicker API for some sort of `change` event and use that.

Comment: thanks @jesus.tesh, I ended up doing that for some of the input fields

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the etiquette for answering my own question rather than editing it, but here what I ended up doing.  per @jesus.tesh suggestion, I added the values (i.e. todays date) to the input fields on page load via server side e.g.

```
<% 
  Dim todaysDate 
  todaysDate = Date()
%>

<input type="text" id="dtpDateEnd" name="dtpDateEnd" value="<%=todaysDate%>" />
```

I also changed my above javascript/jQuery to work better for my needs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $("#dtpDateReturn").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends, dateFormat: 'm/d/yy', changeMonth: true, changeYear: true });
    $("#dtpDateReturn").datepicker("setDate", +1);
});

$(function () {
    $("#dtpDateStart").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'm/d/yy',
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#dtpDateEnd").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
    $("#dtpDateEnd").datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: 'm/d/yy',
        onClose: function (selectedReturnDate) {
            $("#dtpDateReturn").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedReturnDate);
        }
    });

    $("#dtpDateReturn").datepicker( {});
});
```

and it pretty much does what I need